# Response must contain the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header?

Tags: php, html, forms, amp-html

I am getting these errors in the browser

> "Response must contain the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin
>   header"

and

> "Form submission failed: Error: Response must contain the
>   AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header​​​"

**php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['iletisimg'])) {
    $status = 0;
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $time = time();
    if (empty($post->isim) || empty($post->mesaj) || empty($post->email)) {
        $yorumcevap = "Lütfen tüm alanları eksiksiz doldurunuz!";
    } else {
        $yorumekle = $db->query("insert into iletisim (isim,mesaj,email,konu,durum,tarih,ip) values ('$post->isim', '$post->mesaj', '$post->email', '$post->konu', 0, '$time', '$ip')");
        if ($yorumekle) {
            $yorumcevapok = "Teşekkürler. Talebiniz alındı.";
        } else {
            $yorumcevap = "Hata! Lütfen tekrar deneyin.";
        }
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<html amp lang="tr">
<head>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action-xhr="#" autocomplete="off">
    <?PHP echo '<p>' . $yorumcevap . '</p>'; ?>
    <input type="text" class="isim" name="isim" autofocus required>
    <input type="text" class="isim" name="konu" required>
    <input type="text" class="isim" name="email" required>
    <textarea name="mesaj" cols="80" rows="8" required></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Gönder" name="iletisimg">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I edit it this to avoid those errors ?

Comment: You can try checking out this [CORS Security in AMP](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-cors-requests.md#cors-security-in-amp) guide. You can also try looking at these SO posts which were asking about the same error: [48627403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627403/response-must-contain-the-amp-access-control-allow-source-origin-header-i-have), [46264911](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264911/amp-access-control-allow-source-origin-header-issue/46273029#46273029).

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your CORS settings meet the AMP requirements as documented [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/amp-cors-requests)

There's also a similar question which provides the code on how to set the response headers properly:
[AMP Access Control Allow Source Origin header Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264911/amp-access-control-allow-source-origin-header-issue)