# Configuring amp CORS with express

Tags: express, cors, amp-html

I have an express app running on `Firebase Functions` and a static website hosted on `Firebase Hosting`. This static website is a AMP website with a form which makes a post to the express app. When I submit it I get these errors:

> Response must contain the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header
>
> Form submission failed: Error: Response must contain the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header​​​

In my express app:

```
const app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  let origin = req.header('origin').toLowerCase()
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, 
           Content-Type, Accept');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.set("AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin", origin);
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Aside from res.set("AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin", origin);
```

Try including this header as well

```
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin");
```

as mentioned from the [CORS in AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/amp-cors-requests) guide.

You may also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264911/amp-access-control-allow-source-origin-header-issue) for implementation reference.