# AMP action-xhr failed load file 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: php, forms, amp-html

I have a `<form>` in my AMP website and it is not working.

The console keep showing this error message:

> "POST https://www.example.com/submit?__amp_source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.javwebnet.com 403 "

My form page is in `example.com/contactus`.

And the form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action-xhr="/submit.php" target="_top">
<input type="text" name="name" required>
<input type="email" name="email" required>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264911/amp-access-control-allow-source-origin-header-issue ?

Comment: I did and still no luck,I wish I could see another example

Comment: You are not showing the php code where you populate the headers. The part you are showing is irrelevant. The headers should be set in submit.php if I understand your setup correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AMP Access Control Allow Source Origin header Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264911/amp-access-control-allow-source-origin-header-issue)

Comment: I guest the problem is 
    POST https://www.example.com/submit.php?__amp_source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.javwebnet.com 403
maybe thats why it doesnt found the header that set in submit.php

Comment: You are still not showing the code where you set the headers, so the only thing we can do right now is **guess**, a notoriously bad decision making technique...

Comment: I have set the header just like in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264911/amp-access-control-allow-source-origin-header-issue   ... I have try to set the header in the submit.php and  I have try not to user header too..but neither the console show the same error massage... my guess is because the action-xhr failed to load the file (403 forbiden)

Comment: Change https://example.com to https://www.javwebnet.com/

Answer (score 0):

To ensure valid and secure requests and responses for AMP pages, following is a must:

1. Verify the request.
2. Send the appropriate response headers.

If the request is a state change (e.g., POST), check that the origin is from the source origin (via__amp_source_origin) (resource link). After verifying the CORS request, the resulting HTTP response must contain the following headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: 
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin

For, processing state changing requests  that could change the state of the system, check the following:

***If the Origin header is set:***

If the origin does not match one of the following values, stop and return an error response:

- *.ampproject.org
- *.amp.cloudflare.com
- the publisher's origin (aka yours)

where * represents a wildcard match, and not an actual asterisk ( * ).

1. If the value of the __amp_source_origin query parameter is not the publisher's origin, stop and return an error response.
2. If the two checks above pass, process the request.

***If the Origin header is NOT set:***

1. Verify that the request contains the AMP-Same-Origin: true header. If the request does not contain this header, stop and return an error response.
2. Otherwise, process the request.

The below resource links will be helpful:

https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-form/amp-form.md#security-considerations
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/amp-cors-requests
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-cors-requests.md